# Battle pass level 75 when already owning a battle pass

Tags: dota-2

Say I bought the lvl 1 battle pass and I want to buy the lvl 75 battle pass but I'm already level 4. Will it give me the 88 levels as written [here](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/The_International_2017_Battle_Pass_-_Level_75) and put me to 92 or to 88 or won't it work?

If it works, can I buy multiple lvl 75 battle pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, activating a level 75 battle pass while you already own one will level up your battle pass by 88 levels.

Yes, you can purchase more than one.

Comment: Isn't that strange?

Comment: I mean, in that case it's way better just to buy multiple lvl 75 battle pass, no?

Comment: Unless you need fewer than 88 levels.